# I am getting error to install scipy in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I just switched to python 3.8 and I am getting error that scipy is not found so i tried to install it by pip install scipy I am getting error as shown below scipy

Collecting scipy
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/5b/5afcd1c46f97b3c2ac3489dbc95d6ca28eacf8e3634e51f495da68d97f0f/scipy-1.3.1.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w6od1jr0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools 'Cython>=0.29.2' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
cwd: None
Complete output (295 lines):
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
Collecting wheel
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/de/554b6310ac87c5b921bc45634b07b11394fe63bc4cb5176f5240addf18ab/setuptools-41.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Cython>=0.29.2
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/2c/9d873fc8d1be29af12a1d41707461399327396da10e50e183754aa4136b9/Cython-0.29.14-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Collecting numpy==1.14.5
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/6e/f00492653d0fdf6497a181a1c1d46bbea5a2383e7faf4c8ca6d6f3d2581d/numpy-1.14.5.zip
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, Cython, numpy
Running setup.py install for numpy: started
Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-feg73ngb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w6od1jr0\overlay' --compile
cwd: C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy
Complete output (273 lines):
Running from numpy source directory.

```
  Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
  with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

    - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                             release)
    - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


  C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py:464: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
    return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib',
```

'C:\', 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95',
'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
NOT AVAILABLE

```
  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  F2PY Version 2
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib',
```

'C:\', 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

```
  openblas_clapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib        
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs       
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs        
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib        
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs       
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs        
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs        
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib  
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs 
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs        
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jaydeep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running install
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
```

### ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvajwadr\numpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-feg73ngb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w6od1jr0\overlay' --compile Check the logs for full command output.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\jaydeep\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\jaydeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w6od1jr0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools 'Cython>=0.29.2' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: How did you install python?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Visual C++ 14.0 Build tools. In [this link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) look for `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019` under `Tools for Visual Studio 2019` section. Download it and in installation check the C++ Build tool. And also make sure the latest versions of MSVCv142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools and Windows 10 SDK are checked.
for more information see [this link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers).